# Selecting Range by Database Attribute for Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to select a range where the maximum number option is pulled from the database?  I have this code below but it only gives 1 as an option. I'd like it to give the options 1 through the @item.quantity.

```
<%= f.select(:quantity_requested, [1..@item.quantity], {}, { class: 'item-quantity form-control' }) %>
```

All other examples I see are of hard coded numbers.  I would appreciate any help as to understanding why this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen Ruby's range with dynamic numbers. I just tried doing it in irb and it didn't work correctly.  Another alternative would be to use something like this (not tested, but idea is):

```
<%= f.select(:quantity_requested, 1.upto(quantity.times).to_a, {}, { class: 'item-quantity form-control' }) %>
```

**Edit:** 
I just tried this in an irb console and it started at zero based, so you'll want to use upto instead of times, see output below:

```
a = 100
a.times.to_a
=> [0, 1, ... 99]

1.upto(a).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3,.. 99, 100]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Here it is w/ your edit:
<%= f.select(:quantity_requested, 1.upto(@item.quantity).to_a, {}, { class: 'item-quantity form-control' }) %>